# CSS doesn't appear in middle of screen with left: 50% and margin-left: half of the visible value

Tags: css

I created a nice CSS orbit of our solar system, and decides to make EVERYTHING to scale, I already had orbit speed to scale, but not distances between planets, I add the proper distances, and most of it is focused toward the top left meaning I could only see about 25% of the actual thing, the first 3 planets are visible, but only 25% of the time are the other 6 (yes, I'm counting Pluto)

When I made them to scale on the distances it did increase the screen size because one orbit height/width is about 30600 pixels

EDIT: The code may help I'm guessing, also All I really need is to know how to center the sun, from there I can figure it out

```
#sun{
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
height:200px;
width:200px;
margin-top:-100px;
margin-left:-100px;

border: orange 2px solid;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 0 0 64px yellow;
}
```

Comment: we can't help you if we haven't got any code to try stuff on.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Lets start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour then go here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Azrael I know, I was adding the code about the time that you were typing that

Comment: Based on the CSS you've posted your sun should be centered. Could you create a JSFiddle or post the relevant HTML so we can see the issue?

Comment: I tried that before, and it does the same thing, it puts them into the corner

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much figured it out, I just used the max margin-left, which was Pluto's, Then I added that to the suns margin-left (so it became a positive) The requires more work than I Want it to, but it works for centering
EDIT: for the first few it works rather good, but the first planet kinda rotates around a its original fixed point, it looks really weird, but with the planets later on like the 3rd and up, have to be "fine-tuned" it takes a while, if someone else has a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Is it sad that that took me about 2 days to think of?

Comment: Not at all. I'm glad you got it figured out. Good luck moving forward sounds like an interesting project